# Manter o Scroll na [ultima posição depois de uma requisição AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rolamento

Eu estou tendo dificuldades em realizar uma atividade que é manter o scroll na ÚLTIMA posição antes da requisição AJAX.

```
//antes da requisição
 var scrollPosition = $('.cart').scrollTop();

==> REQUISIÇÃO

$.ajax({...})
.done(function () {
//depois da requisição
$('.cart').scrollTop(scrollPosition)
 })
```

Quando eu realizo dessa forma o scroll fica subindo pouco a pouco a cada requisição.

Se eu usar animate:

```
('.cart').animate({scrollTop: scrollPosition})
```

O código funciona contudo eu preciso fazer com que o scroll fique FIXO, pois ao usar o animate, o scroll desce do top até a posição.

Se tiver também uma forma com que ao dar refresh o AJAX não altere o scroll seria uma boa.

Já tentei por localStorage/sessionStorage e não funciona.

O que tá me deixando com bastante dúvidas é porque o Scroll sobe pouco a pouco a cada refresh.

**só posso usar JQUERY**

Answer (score 0):

você pode criar um elemento fixo logo após onde vai inserir o resultado para fazer desta forma:

```js
$(".click").click(function(){
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".elementofixo").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
<p>texto</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>texto</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>texto</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>texto</p>
<button class='click'>clik teste</button>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>texto</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>texto</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>texto</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class='elementofixo'></div>
</div>
```

Este é apenas um evento onde vc clica no botão que esta no meio da tela e ele não volta do inicio e sim só da scroll ate o elemento fixo. mas pode te ajudar vc chama este evento quando adicionar elementos na tela.